# micro-framework for command applications to process data, either in php or python?

Tags: php, python, command-line, command

Here is what I use to build a php command line applications to process data.

These applications are not web applications, they run in command line shell to process some data.

Due to the Legacy reason, I use Laravel php framework.

So I use Laravel "Artisan Development" to build custom commands and then run the commands use

```
php artisan ...
```

Laravel is for a web app, but now, I am only using its artisan commands. It seems an overkill, that I install the full version Laravel Framework for this purpose.

But I could not find a good php micro-framework specially to building commands application.

My questions are

- Like Lumen, a micro-framework by Laravel for API, do you have any laravel/php micro-framework for commands you can recommend?
- Or are there any python micro-frameworks for command applications you can recommend? I googled, "Click" is recommended. Any frameworks else?

Thanks!

Comment: I have one I made if you want it, [Github](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Cli) its about as small as it gets, it's like 1 file.  Should be pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python, I definitely recommend [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/). It has become ***the*** Python library for creating command line tools. It's written/maintained by the author of [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (currently the #5 most-starred Python repo on GitHub). I use Click all the time when creating command line tools. It has everything most people would need.

Not sure what your definition of a micro-framework is, but Click has no external dependencies and takes up approx. 500 KB (including .pyc files) when I install it. Also, it doesn't really require any boilerplate to setup and start using. So I guess I would call it a micro-framework.

Comment: https://github.com/google/python-fire

How about Python Fire? If I am going to run the commands on GCP, would python-fire be a good selection too? due to it is Google supported?

Answer (score 1):

I made this small library,

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Cli

Your welcome to use it Or get inspiration from it, basically its a wrapper around `getopt()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

> getopt — Gets options from the command line argument list

You can get it on composer too:

```
"require" : {
    "evo/cli" : "~1.0"
}
```

Basic usage is like this:

```
$Cli = Cli::getInstance();
$Cli->setArgument('h', 'help', 'Show this help document');
//... other arguments 
if($Cli->getArgument('h')) $Cli->printHelpDoc(); //exits
```

And so on.

You can even do it from a PHP config file, which just gets put into `setArgument()` ~ basically.

```
//config.php
return [
         [
           'shortName' => 'h',
           'longName' => 'help',
           'doc' => 'Show this help document'
         ]
      ];
```

Then

```
  //cli.php

  $config = require 'config.php';

  $Cli = Cli::getInstance();
  $Cli->fromConfig($config);

  if($Cli->getArgument('h')) $Cli->printHelpDoc(); //exits
```

You can also do dynamic validation of the input args like this (with a closure):

```
    $Cli->setArgument('f', 'foo', 'This is just foo, and must always be foo', [
        'accept' => function($shortName, $value){
            if($value == 'foo') return true;
            return false;
        }
    ]);
```

The above just returns a Boolean, if the value is good or not. If you return false it will issue an exception, etc. You can also make an argument required like this:

```
   $Cli->setArgument('i', 'input', 'This is input that requires a value', [
       'requireValue' => true
   ]);
```

And of course you can combine those 2.

There is some documentation on the Github page.  It has a few small dependencies, just common stuff that I like to re-use (all in composer).  Together it's less then 1000 lines of code.  Maybe 20 or 30kb.

I needed to make a small command line thing, and I had this idea...